# How to add event handler programmatically in WPF like one can do in Winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

What's the equivalent of this winform instruction:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

in WPF ?

Update: also for a slider. And what namespace should I declare ?

My point is NOT to use XAML.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this...

```
this.btnTest.Click+=new RoutedEventHandler(btnTest_Click);
```

Comment: In fact also need for slider. seems like different from button

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
 button1.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click));
```

then you have to create a function like this

```
void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're adding the new event from the XAML side, the IDE does most of the work for you.

For instance, if you type

```
<Button Name="button1" Click=
```

then the IDE will pop up with a drop-down of all your currently created events.

You can select one of your previously-created events, or create a new one by selecting "New Event Handler"

If you select "New Event Handler", then VS automatically adds the skeleton for you in the form.xaml.cs C# code-behind.  You just add whatever you'd like the click event to do inside the already-made skeleton.

Comment: Yeah, but it helps for people like the OP to actually know how things work when the UI abstraction layer breaks down.

Comment: @Ed Swangren, that's definitely true, the above technique is just what I've always used in my little programming experience and it hasn't failed yet, so I keep rolling with it :)

Comment: Of course, that is what I would do to because I know how things are working under the covers.  Unfortunately, abstractions are best used by people who can see through them ;)

Comment: I don't want to use xaml for this so my question.

Answer (score 0):

WPF isn't a new language, i.e., it's exactly the same concept. The only thing that may change is the delegate type.  So yeah, you would do it the same way.

Comment: doesn't seem so for me. For example button and slider don't seem similar like in winform. Still searching for the right syntax for slider.

Comment: It's not a question of syntax; you are using C# whether your UI API is WinForms or WPF.  You are likely just not assigning the correct delegate type.  It helps to tell us what error you are receiving.

Comment: @Ed Swangren, but aren't some of the libraries slightly different from Winforms to WPF? I know that just programming in winforms vs Silverlight that although it is indeed both C# code-behind, the syntax/property names are different for the exact same task.  WPF may be different, though.  I thought all three used slightly different libraries, though.  I may be wrong.

Comment: You are confusing syntax with the API.  The syntax is defined by the language spec.  Yes, the libraries are different, which is what I was saying above.

Comment: @Ed Swangren, Ah, ok, I apologize, I misunderstood what you were saying

Comment: @Ed call this syntax or not syntax, my problem stays the same: I don't know how / what library namespace event name handler I should use.

Comment: And it doesn't seem to have much on the internet !

Comment: Well, that is pretty simple assuming you know the type of the button.  Took me all of two seconds to find the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx

Comment: As you can see, the delegate type is RoutedEventHandler, so you need to assign one of those instead of an EventHandler delegate as you would in WinForms.

Comment: I'm not asking for Button : I know for button. I'm asking for slider.

Comment: Really wpf is exactly same concepts ? I think you REALLY know WPF as it is said here: One of the most daunting things about getting up to speed on Windows® Presentation Foundation (WPF) is that there are so many new constructs to master. Even simple things like Microsoft® .NET Framework properties and events have new counterparts in WPF with added capabilities and associated complexity—specifically dependency properties and routed events. Then there is all the brand new stuff, such as animations, styling, control templates, and routed commands. There is a lot to learn.

Comment: Please read more slowly. I said that it isn't a new *language*, i.e., if you know how to subscribe to an event in C# it doesn't matter if you are using WinForms or WPF for your UI.