# Programatically customize context menu item in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, wpfdatagrid, menuitem

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio using C# and WPF. I have a Datagrid and I would like to Programatically create/customize its context menu items.

Here is how I'm currently creating the menu item:

```
        MenuItem Enable;
        Enable = new MenuItem();

        dgdProcessList.ContextMenu.Items.Add(Enable);
        Enable.Header = "Enable";
```

Now I want to place a icon for that menu item, however I am having trouble figuring out how can I point the icon to an existing file in the project. It's currently located in Resources\Icons\SampleIcon.ico of my project. How do I properly reference it here:

```
Enable.Icon = ???;
```

Also, I would like this menu item to trigger a function when clicked. How do I do this with the following code:

```
Enable.Click = ???;
```

Apologies if this is something simple. I looked at various topics relating to this issue, but wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: Here is example how to set Icon https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671/6064728

Comment: And here is example of the event handler for click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663372/how-to-add-event-handler-programmatically-in-wpf-like-one-can-do-in-winform

Comment: Have you at least tried to search an answer before asking question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
var imgEdit = (BitmapImage) Application.Current.FindResource("Edit");
var mnu = new MenuItem {Header = title};
if (imgEdit != null) mnu.Icon = new Image {Height = 16, Width = 16, Source = imgEdit};
```

As long as your icon is in a ResourceDictionary that is referenced in your App.xaml you should be good ie:

Put this in your ResourceDictionary:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="/MyApp;component/Images/Light/edit.png" x:Key="Edit" PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" />
```

And have this in your App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ImageStyles.xaml" />
```

And to enable the Click do something like so:

```
mnu.Click += (o, e) => callback();
```